# Getting java.sql.SQLException: Access denied for user ''@'localhost' (using password: NO)

Tags: java, mysql, spring, spring-boot, hibernate

I am trying to build and learn about Spring boot application but when I am starting my application getting this error:

```
java.sql.SQLException: Access denied for user ''@'localhost' (using password: NO)
```

Here is my `application.properties` file configuration:

```
#changing server port at localhost
server.port=8080

#mysql database configuration
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/myhiber
spring.datasource.data-username= root
spring.datasource.data-password= password
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver

#Hibernate Configuration
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL57Dialect
```

I have tried many online solution for this but nothing worked for me some solutions which is tried:

- Provided Permission to root user
- I am able to connect MySQL direct with my shell

Help me please with that.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Your properties are wrong.

Change **from** `spring.datasource.data-username` **to** `spring.datasource.username`

and

**from** `spring.datasource.data-password` **to** `spring.datasource.password`.

**Explanation**:

`spring.datasource.username` and `spring.datasource.password` are used to do the authentication in the database.

`spring.datasource.data-username` and `spring.datasource.data-password` are used to authenticate when doing DML commands and are intended to be used if they are different from `spring.datasource.username` and `spring.datasource.password`.

This is explained in the docs, see **[here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#spring.datasource.data-password)**.

So, when you set only `spring.datasource.data-username` and `spring.datasource.data-password`, Spring doesn't know how to authenticate to the database (as you saw by the error `Access denied for user ''@'localhost'`, the user is blank), because these properties are not intended to be used in this stage.

Comment: matheus-cirillo thanks for your suggestion, now it worked. but still i have one question, when to use data-username then?

Comment: @ph1b3r0p1c . . . I've added an explanation to my answer, see if this answer your question. . .

Comment: thankss a lot for your explaination, i understand now, thanks for your time, i need to learn a lot.